# trigger click event on href if condition on same href is true in angular

Tags: angular

Automatically trigger click event on href if condition on same href is true in angular

```
<a (click)="{(subCategory.show == true)?#myId}" >item name  </a>

<div id="myId"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this but **this will only work if your hide function works**

```js
document.getElementById("myId").click();
```

Comment: Can you explain where is the `href` here ?

Comment: you need a ```href```?? I thought this was supposed to hide or unhide an element